# Tuning Hive Queries That Uses Underlying HBase Table

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, hbase, integration

I've got a table in Hbase let's say "tbl" and I would like to query it using
Hive. Therefore I mapped a table to hive as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl(id string, data map<string,string>)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,data:")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "tbl");
```

Queries like:

```
select * from tbl", "select id from tbl", "select id, data
from tbl
```

are really fast.

But queries like

```
select id from tbl where substr(id, 0, 5) = "12345"

select id from tbl where data["777"] IS NOT NULL
```

are incredibly slow.

In the contrary when running from Hbase shell:

```
"scan 'tbl', {
COLUMNS=>'data', STARTROW='12345', ENDROW='12346'}" or
"scan 'tbl', { COLUMNS=>'data', "FILTER" =>
FilterList.new([qualifierFilter('777')])}"
```

it is lightning fast!

When I looked into the mapred job generated by hive on jobtracker I
discovered that "map.input.records" counts ALL the items in Hbase table,
meaning the job makes a full table scan before it even starts any mappers!!
Moreover, I suspect it copies all the data from Hbase table to hdfs to
mapper tmp input folder before executuion.

So, my questions are - Why hbase storage handler for hive does not translate
hive queries into appropriate hbase functions? Why it scans all the records
and then slices them using "where" clause? How can it be improved?

Any suggestions to improve the performance of Hive queries(mapped to HBase Table).

Can we create secondary index on HBase tables?

We are using HBase and Hive integration and trying to tune the performance of Hive queries.

Comment: Do you have any figures for queries that run against Hive's Text vs ORC vs HBase integration ? How do Tpch queries fare against above storage formats? Thanks and Regards!

Comment: Hey @Ram, have you ever found a proper solution/workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 17):

Lots of questions!, I'll try to answer all and give you a few performance tips:

The data is not copied to the HDFS, but the mapreduce jobs generated by HIVE will store their intermediate data in the HDFS.

Secondary indexes or alternative query paths are not supported by HBase ([more info](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#secondary.indexes)).

Hive will translate everything into MapReduce jobs which need time to be distributed & initialized, if you have a very small number of rows its possible that a simple SCAN operation in the Hbase shell is faster than a Hive query but on big datasets, distributing the job among the datanodes is a must.

The Hive HBase handler doesn't do a very good job when extracting the start & stop row keys from the query, queries like `substr(id, 0, 5) = "12345"` won't use start & stop row keys.

Before executing your queries, run a `EXPLAIN [your_query];` command and check for the **`filterExpr:`** part, if you don't find it, your query will perform a full table scan. On a side note, all expresions within the **`Filter Operator:`** will be transformed into the appropiate filters.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (id>='12345') AND (id<'12346')
STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Alias -> Map Operator Tree:
        tbl 
          TableScan
            alias: tbl 
            filterExpr:
                expr: ((id>= '12345') and (id < '12346'))
                type: boolean
            Filter Operator
                ....
```

Fortunately, there is an easy way to make sure start & stop row keys are used when you're looking for row-key prefixes, just convert `substr(id, 0, 5) = "12345"` to a simpler query: `id>="12345" AND id<"12346"`, it will be detected by the handler and start & stop row keys will be provided to the SCAN (12345, 12346)

---

Now, here are a few tips in order to speed up your queries (by a lot):

- Make sure you set the following properties to take advantage of batching to reduce the number of RPC calls (the number depends on the size of your columns)

  `SET hbase.scan.cache=10000;`

  `SET hbase.client.scanner.cache=10000;`
- Make sure you set the following properties to run a distributed job in your task trackers instead of running local job.

  `SET mapred.job.tracker=[YOUR_JOB_TRACKER]:8021;`

  `SET hbase.zookeeper.quorum=[ZOOKEEPER_NODE_1],[ZOOKEEPER_NODE_2],[ZOOKEEPER_NODE_3];`
- Reduce the amount of columns of your SELECT statement to the minimum. Try not to `SELECT *`
- Whenever you want to use start & stop row keys to prevent full table scans, always provide `key>=x` and `key<y` expressions (don't use the BETWEEN operator)
- Always `EXPLAIN SELECT` your queries before executing them.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. Is there a way to apply hints in hive while fetching the data from HBase (e.g cluster by in hive).

Comment: I'm not very sure about what you would like to achieve with that but I'm pretty sure it's not supported. If you're concerned about reducing the amount of network I/O, the MR jobs generated by Hive and the underlying system will be intelligent enough to distribute the scan along the regionservers where each region data resides locally. Give it a try and let me know ;)

Comment: Do you have any figures for queries that run against Hive's Text vs ORC vs HBase integration ? How do Tpch queries fare against all above storage formats?

Comment: Will the above be possible also for an HBASE table JOIN with a HIVE table?

Comment: @thebluephantom Yes it would. The key is to make sure every queried table get a filterExpr in order to avoid a full table scan.

Comment: To be clear, a hive table scanned and joined to hbase key with start stop key will work? If so then great but some confusion in the various blogs. I do not want to put literals in but have the scanning stop start keys dynamically set. @RUBENMORALEDA

Comment: I don't think the start stop key stuff you state can work with a massive JOIN. @RubénMoraleda